# Running ASP.Net server - Must be from visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, webserver

I'm pretty new to ASP.Net and I've been having troubles understanding something.

1. I made a web application project with a web service on my computer.
2. I made another web application project, who then consumed the WSDL from the web service on the first project and uses a function in it.

I ran each on a different VS2012 Instance and when both projects are running in then there is no problem and it works fine.
When i close the VS Instance with the Web Service project then I get a Coonnection Error which is also logical.

My question:
Is there a way to keep the server running without keeping visual studio open?
There is no ".exe" generated or anything so I don't know what to run in order to keep the "Server" running..

Additional question if you don't mind:
If I want to use this service from another computer on the same Network, will the "localhost:.....?WSDL" service reference still work or do I need another address?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I just couldn't find a good guide explaining about how to keep the server running anywhere.

Thank you, Mellor.

Comment: use IIS to host service

Answer (score 0):

1. Host your web service in localhost
2. use the computername instead of localhost in WSDL URL when you add services/web reference in cleint applications

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you.
1. How do I host services? Can you link me to a guide?
2. Okay, so if it was "localhost:12312........?WSDL" I need to change it to "CompName:12312......?WSDL" ? Do I also need to change the endpoint address?

Comment: 1. For How to Host Web Service in IIS follow the steps mentioned in the following post  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93196f66-c11f-4121-8454-738f8e876508/how-to-host-web-service-in-iis-

Comment: 2.Yes, After hosting in IIS you have to replace localhost with yourcomputername when you add services/web reference in cleint applications. Do change endpoint address for better readability in config of your service but it is not mandatory. Your clients however needs to use the endpoint that has the servername instead of localhost